# Help with old exam question relating a spanning set of covectors of $T_{p}^{*} M$ to a coordinate chart containing $p$.

Tags: geometry, smooth-manifolds

This question came up on my exam yesterday, and I still can't seem to come up with the proof for it:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold and suppose that $y^1, \ldots, y^n \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Show that, if the covectors $(dy^i)_p$ span $T_{p}^{*}M$ at some $p \in M$, then there is a coordinate chart about $p$ whose components agree with the functions $y^i$.

I see that $\{(dy^i)_p\}$ is a basis for $T_{p}^{*}M$, and thus is dual to a basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial y^{i}}\big|_{p}\right\}$ for $T_p M$, but I'm not sure how to guarantee that I can pull from this basis a coordinate chart about $M$. Can anyone shed some light on this proof for me? I overheard a fellow classmate talk about the inverse function theorem, but it's not clear to me how it applies.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can use the functions $y^1,\dots,y^n$ to define a function to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and using the fact you know, that their differentials form a basis for $T_{p}^{\ast}M$, the differential of this function to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ at $p\in M$ will be an isomorphism. Thus using the invers function theorem you get a local difeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $f: M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(q)=(y^1(q), \dots, y^n(q))$. Fix $p \in M$.

If the covectors $(dy^i)_p$ span $T_p^*M$, then this tells you that the linear map $df_p: T_pM \to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces. There are many ways to show this: one indirect method is just to note that the dual map $\delta f_p: T_{f(p)}^*\mathbb{R}^n \to T_p^*M$ is an isomorphism, since $\delta f_p(d\pi^j_{f(p)})=d\pi^j_{f(p)} \circ df_p = d(\pi^j \circ f)_p=dy^j_p$, i.e, basis vectors are sent to basis vectors.

Therefore, by the inverse function theorem, you can say that there exist neighborhoods $U \ni p$ and $V \ni f(p)$ on which $f$ acts as a diffeomorphism. In particular, $(f,U)$ is a coordinate chart on $M$.

Comment: Doh! That makes perfect sense and is so much cleaner than what I was trying to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah sure no problem :)