# Forming a chart of a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$, let $m < n$, $x_1, \ldots, x_m: U \to \mathbb R$, where $U$ is an open subset of $M$, be smooth functions such that $dx_1, \ldots, dx_n$ are linearly independent at $(T_pM)^{\ast}$ for each $p \in U$, then $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ can be completed to a chart of $M$.

The idea seems straightforward, just take a basis of $(T_pM)^{\ast}$, say $dx_1,\ldots, dx_m, y_{m+1}, \ldots, y_{n}$, then the idea is to locate functions $f_{m+1}, \ldots, f_{m+n}$ such that $df_{m+1} = y_{m+1}, \ldots, df_{n} = y_{n}$. How should I do this?

Some Clarification: The new chart is not necessarily required to take values on the whole $U$. The idea is that if we can find functions $df_{m+1} = y_{m+1}, \ldots, df_{m+n} = y_{m+n}$, then by inverse function theorem, in a suitable neighborhood, we can form a chart.

Update: This statement comes from the [notes](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~azinger/mat531-spr11/lect1to7.pdf) of Prof.Alexy Zinger(corollary 4.12 on page23)

Comment: You may want to look at this previous question:<https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206958/help-with-old-exam-question-relating-a-spanning-set-of-covectors-of-t-p-m?rq=1>

Comment: That is entirely different from what I am asking I think. @JoelPereira

Comment: Completing the basis of $(T_pM)^*$ gives an isomorphism of $(T_pM)^*$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$. This isomorphism is induced by map from M to $\mathbb{R}^n$. This map will be a local diffeomorphism. This diffeomorphism gives you the chart you need.

Comment: What I am asking is how to complete the basis, i.e., I am looking for maps whose differentials correspond to the basis. @JoelPereira

Comment: You have that $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ are linearly independent at $(T_P M)^*$. Where did the $dx_{m+1},\dots, dx_n$ come from? I thought you only let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ exist in the statement.  Also, what is this star notation?

Comment: The star means the cotangent space which is the dual of $T_pM$, and it is $n$ dimensional so you can complete an independent set to a basis.

Comment: You have to be careful about the definition of your new chart. To me, is not even true you can find a chart defined in the whole $U$, but instead in a possibly smaller neighborhood of each $p$. Plus, you took $y_{m+1}, \dots, y_{m+n}$ to be just functionals in $T_pM$, I would locally trivialize $T^*M$ and the try to prove what you say.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Sorry for the confusion @Laz

Comment: Uh you can't go to $m+n$ if $\dim M = n$

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.@IAmNoOne

Comment: Aren't the notes doing something different? There the $y_j$ are the coordinate functions of some chart, so that the $d_p y_j$ span $T_p^* M$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer this question. Given $V_p \neq 0$, a covector in $(T_pM)^{\ast}$, I claim that I can cook up a smooth function $f: U \mathbb \to \mathbb R$, where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, such that $(df)_p = V_p$. Take the dual vector $W_p$ of $V_p$ in $T_pM$, can extend it to a vector field $W$ on $M$. Take its integral curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, such that $\gamma(0) = p, \dot \gamma(0) = W_p$. Then by inverse function theorem $\gamma$ has an inverse in around a neighborhood of $0$, say $\gamma^{-1}$. Notice that $d\gamma^{-1}_{p}\gamma_{0}= d\gamma^{-1}_p d\gamma_{0} = Id_{T_0(\text{some open subset of} (-\epsilon, \epsilon))}$, which implies that $d\gamma^{-1}_pd\gamma_{0}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{0}) = d\gamma_p^{-1}(W_p) = 1$. So $d\gamma_p = V_p$.

Comment: But $\gamma^{-1}$ isn't defined on an open subset of $M$; it's only defined on a subset of the curve $\gamma((-\epsilon, \epsilon))$. The inverse function theorem only gives you an inverse between manifolds of the same dimension.